# FSA Comet (CKM-7158T) crank removal problem. How to?

Tags: crankset

I am dissembling an FSA Comet crankset, and I have removed the self extracting bolt from the drive side. But I cannot remove the crank arm, it is sitting super tight.

I am hitting it pretty hard with rubber hummer, and it doesn't move at all. Is there any way to safely remove it? I'm affraid I might damage my carbon frame.﻿
Thank you!

Comment: Can you reinsert the self extractor?

Comment: stop hitting it with a hammer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'self-extracting' bolt is there to help remove the crank. It needs to go back in. Thread the bolt back into the axle and then insert and tighten fully the retaining ring, possibly a left hand thread. Finally you can undo the bolt, which will push against the retaining ring to gently push the crank off.

There's a really good (imo) video by Park Tool here if you like that sort of thing

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my day! I looked through FSA documention, which is very poor, and it felt like I need to remove the bolt first. But with it on, it worked like a char. Thanks again!

Comment: no problemo, p.s. don't thank me, thank Calvin Jones

Answer (score 3):

Use the self extractor. Most two-piece road and mountain cranks that have self extractors don't at this point feature any other real way to do it, even if a conventional type puller could in theory be made for them. FSA in particular has about a million different threads they use for the extraction threads. If tools for them all exist, they're not commonplace.